# Удалить смещение для следующих элементов

Tags: css

Есть структура страницы

```
block1
block2
block3
```

Блоку `block2` прописано `{position: relative; top: -100px }`, что бы он наползал на `block1` - это сделано специально.

Но после этого расстояние между `block2` и `block3` становится равному тому числу, на которое поднят `block2`

Как сделать так, что бы `block3` шел прямо за `block2`, без отступа?

Приходит в голову только назначить блоку 3 такое же смещение наверх, но на самом деле на странице много абзацев, картинок и прочего, поэтому слишком много нужно прописывать. Причем, я заранее не знаю, какие элементы будут на странице.

Какой есть выход?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

У block-3 необходимо установить margin-top: -Npx и тогда все нижние блоки (block-4, block-5) так же сместятся вверх (примут контекстное положение блока block-3).

Comment: Вы гений ! :) все получилось
я знал, что есть нормальное решение